# Java Script Conditions

Tags: javascript

what's wrong with this function and why it doesn't work? 
I was trying to do this:
1. Write a function that that is called divide. It should take in 1 parapeter, which is a number.
2. If the number is larger than 20 divide it with 4 and return that number.
3. If the number is larger than 10 divide it with 3 and return that number.
4. Else divide it with 2 and return that number.

```
function divide(x) {
    if (x > 20) {
        document.write(x / 4);
    }
    else if (x > 10) {
        document.write(x / 3);
    } else {
        document.write(x / 2);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = divide(23);
}
```

Comment: Writing a document does not return a value. You don't return a value. That's probably what's wrong.

Comment: Can you specify what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: You are not returning.... You are using document.write and you have a syntax error which the developer console should inform you about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to recursively call `divide`, so put the part that invokes `divide` outside the method. Otherwise, you're on the [right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53055311/2970947). We can add a `div` with that `id` and run it here. Like,

```js
function divide(x) {
  if (x > 20) {
    return x / 4;
  } else if (x > 10) {
    return x / 3;
  } else {
    return x / 2;
  }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = divide(23);
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is just what I needed